# What are the differences between Windows 7 RC and the RTM?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am currently running the Windows 7 RC (build 7100) which works like a charm. With the news about the RTM build and the upcoming release, I am wondering what the differences are between the two builds.

I've searched for comparisons or release notes, but have not been able to find any.

Comment: It's hard to really find anything substantial, so you're not alone in your searching failure...

Comment: As the RC was feature-complete the path to RTM only consisted of bug fixes. So nothing has changed except errors, bugs and glitches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul Thurrott has a [full breakdown](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/ff.asp) of the features included in Windows 7 RTM.

I know that the [Guest Mode](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/ff_pcsafeguard.asp) feature has been removed from Windows 7.

Comment: Paul's guide is good, but it doesn't address any changes between builds 7100 and 7600.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Release Candidate (RC) testing. its pre-release software, You can get to see what's coming, and get to see if changes and fixes from the Beta testing are working correctly.
(http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/download.aspx)

Windows RTM : It stands for Release to Manufacturers. RTM means that the code for Windows will be finalized and partners will receive it and start preparations to launch new PCs.
(http://www.ithinkdiff.com/windows-7-rtm-faq/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I understand the theoretical differences between a RC and RTM, but am mainly looking for concrete differences in application structure, interface, etc. Thanks, though :)

Comment: I also missed the part in the question where the author was asking for the definitions of the acroymns.